# Unable to parse full html page into document

Tags: java, html, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

Here in this code i wanted to parse whole html file(local) into document variable but i observe that it is only parsing less than 10% of the content. Please Help!!

```
Document doc=null;
HashSet<String>urlSet=null;
try {
    doc = Jsoup.parse(file,null);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return urlSet;
}

urlSet=getLinks(doc);
if(urlSet!=null)
    urlSet=refineURLs(urlSet);
return urlSet;
```

Comment: How big is the ```file``` String in byte?

Comment: html file size if 100kb. It is downloaded from this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developmental_biology and saved as html file.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of relative links in the html.
Use this instead:

```
String html = readFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), Charset.defaultCharset());
doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developmental_biology");

private static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException {
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    return new String(encoded, encoding);
}
```

Comment: you want me to create a method "readFile()" ? can you please elaborate this function?